# drawing a curve in latex with my own data

Tags: graphics

I would like to draw a curve in latex LaTeX with my own datahow . How please I can do that.? this This is my table that contains the data....

**EDIT**

this is 2 new files

```
%test.dat   

Num Min Moy Max
R1 100 100 100
R2 100 100 100
R3 250 250 250
R4 250 250 250
R5 500 500 500
R6 500 500 500
R7 750 750 750
R8 750 750 750
R9 1000 1000 1000
R10 1000 1000 1000
```

and this is his code

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[%
      % Lengend position
      legend pos = outer north east,
      % We need a tick for every data
      xtick = data,
      % The ticks label are provided in the file as the column named Num
      xticklabels from table = {test2.dat}{Num}]
    % How the data are separated.
   % \pgfplotstableset{col sep = tab}
    % We need to simulate an x coord since it is litteral in the data file. I choose to index on the line.
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Min] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Min}
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Moy] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Moy}
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Max] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Max}
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Pub Partagée avec des pages dont la politique est Tout le Monde et ayant un Nb Min, Moy Max d'amis}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: please if someone have an idea he tell me

Comment: @Jake: ok I will do that in the future but really I don't know how to do that in the previous time but since you tell me I will do that by myself

Comment: @Jake: please do you have an idea to resolve my problem?

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure you're plotting the right file (maybe you're mixing up `data.dat` and `data2.dat`)?

Comment: @Jake: when you say that works fine for you the curve that you obtain reach 1000 in the axe of y or he just reach 500? because for me it reach only 500

Comment: Yeah, they all reach 1000 (and they're all identical). Try changing a single value in your datafile to something extreme, like 5000, to see if you're really plotting the right file.

Comment: @Jake: even when I change the value to 5000 nothing is done but I'm sure that I'm plotting the right file but perhaps I must change the size of my figure because I note that the figure is placed in the middile of the page although the page is empty.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your output in the question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3365/discussion-between-jake-and-boutheina)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For simplicity, I provide the data as a file, values are separated by tabs and I added a title to the samples.

```
% This is test.dat
Num Min Moy Max
R1  25.66   33  39.66
R2  40.2    48.16   56.66
R3  67.5    82  98.33
R4  104.83  125 141.5
R5  141  164    189.5
R6  211  236    259.66
R7  219  247    279.14
R8  316.75  355 392
R9  283.66  326 362.75
R10 427.5   471 513.42
% End of test.dat
```

The source code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      % Lengend position
      legend pos = outer north east,
      % We need a tick for every data
      xtick = data,
      % The ticks label are provided in the file as the column named Num
      xticklabels from table = {test.dat}{Num},
      title = {\Large\bfseries This is my curves}]
    % We need to simulate an x coord since it is litteral in the data file. I choose to index on the line.
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Min] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Min}
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Moy] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Moy}
    \addplot table [x expr = \lineno, y = Max] {test.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Max}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @boutheina See if the copy/paste preserved the tab separator in the file `test.dat`.

Comment: @cjorssen: I see my file test.dat and it is write in the right form I use the tab but these errors appear again:! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'Min' from table '\\pgfplotstableread@filename@@table@name '. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...le [x expr = \lineno, y = Min] {test.dat};

Comment: @Jake: when you use the code suggested by cjorssen it work?

Comment: @Jake: Thank you very much  when I remove the line  \pgfplotstableset{col sep = tab} the code is compilated thank you thank you

Comment: @Jake Thanks. Answer edited according to your suggestion.

Comment: @Jake: Can I put a title to my curve and can I put it in the center and enlarge it please?

Comment: @boutheina Title added.

Comment: @jake cjorssen: I have a  pb that is stongly linked with the the first. In addition to this curve I would like to draw 2 others curves that has as y 1000 but when I put this in my file the axe of y doesn't reach 1000 it still at 500

Comment: @boutheina Can you edit your question with those new requirements?

Comment: :I edit my code do you have an idea please?

Comment: I would like to add a name to the axe of Y in the figure how I can make that please?